# Read and loop through all contents in a file separated by tab and put all the words in an ArrayList

Tags: java, file-io, tabs

I'm working on a java project for school and I want to read all words in a text file and store it in an Arraylist. Here is a small sample of the text file:

```
1876    Gore    Vidal   Random House    4/11/1976   Fiction
23337   Stephen King    Scribner    11/27/2011  Fiction
...and Ladies of the Club   Helen Hooven    Santmeyer   Putnam  7/8/1984    Fiction
1st to Die  James   Patterson   Little, Brown   3/25/2001   Fiction
2nd Chance  James   Patterson   Little, Brown   3/24/2002   Fiction
3rd Degree  James   Patterson   Little, Brown   3/21/2004   Fiction
4th of July James   Patterson   Little, Brown   5/22/2005   Fiction
```

There is a tab character between the fields.
The code I have only reads through the first line not the full list.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("bestsellers.txt");
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        String lineJustFetched = null;
        String[] wordsArray;
        Book CurrentBook = new Book();
        while (true) {
            lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
            if (lineJustFetched == null) {
                break;
            } else {
                wordsArray = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
                for (String each : wordsArray) {
                    if (!"".equals(each)) {
                        words.add(each);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        CurrentBook.title = words.get(0);
        CurrentBook.authorFirstName = words.get(1);
        CurrentBook.authorLastName = words.get(2);
        CurrentBook.publisher = words.get(3);
        CurrentBook.category = words.get(5);
        CurrentBook.date = words.get(4);
        buf.close();
        System.out.println("Author's first name is: " + CurrentBook.authorFirstName);
        System.out.println("Author's last name is: " + CurrentBook.authorLastName);
        System.out.println("Title is: " + CurrentBook.title);
        System.out.println("The publisher is: " + CurrentBook.publisher);
        System.out.println("The category is: " + CurrentBook.category);
        System.out.println("The date is: " + CurrentBook.date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Author's first name is: Gore
Author's last name is: Vidal
Title is: 1876
The publisher is: Random House
The category is: Fiction
The date is: 4/11/1976
```

As you can see, it only reads, stores, and prints the first book but I want to do this for all the words in the txt file.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: so what is the problem? Are you having trouble iterating over your arraylist?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stores all the books, but you only print one. Instead of assigning the variables using `Book.String = words.get[i]`, use a constructor that assigns it for you in the Book Class, such as:

```
public Book(String title, String authorFirstName, String authorLastName, String publisher, String category, String data) {
this.title = title;
this.authorFirstName = authorFirstName;
this.authorLastName = authorFirstName;
this.publisher = publisher;
this.category = category;
this.data = data;
}
```

Now in your main method replace `Book() CurrentBook = new Book();` with `ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();`, this is where the fun happens.
Delete `ArrayList<String> words`, you don't need it anymore, and change your while loop to the one below.

```
while (!(buf.readLine() == null) {
            lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
             wordsArray = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
                books.add(new Book(wordsArray[0], wordsArray[1], wordsArray[2], wordsArray[3], wordsArray[4], wordsArray[5]));
            }
```

In all your reformed main would be

```
 try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("bestsellers.txt");
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!(buf.readLine() == null) {
            String lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
             String[] wordsArray = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
                books.add(new Book(wordsArray[0], wordsArray[1], wordsArray[2], wordsArray[3], wordsArray[4], wordsArray[5]));
            }
        buf.close();
       for (int i = 0; i < books.size; i++) {
        System.out.println("Author's first name is: " + books.get(i).authorFirstName);
        System.out.println("Author's last name is: " + books.get(i).authorLastName);
        System.out.println("Title is: " + books.get(i).title);
        System.out.println("The publisher is: " + books.get(i).publisher);
        System.out.println("The category is: " + books.get(i).category);
        System.out.println("The date is: " + books.get(i).date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the method you would want to use honoring your code, however since you used an object for your books I'm assuming you would want to integrate a lookup later, so you would make a HashMap and store your data for later down the line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("bestsellers.txt");
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, Book> bookCollectiion = new HashMap<>();
        while (!(buf.readLine() == null) {
            String lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
             String[] wordsArray = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
                books.add(new Book(wordsArray[0], wordsArray[1], wordsArray[2], wordsArray[3], wordsArray[4], wordsArray[5]));
            }
        buf.close();
       for (int i = 0; i < books.size; i++) {
        bookCollection.put(books.get(i).title, books.get(i));
        System.out.println("Author's first name is: " + books.get(i).authorFirstName);
        System.out.println("Author's last name is: " + books.get(i).authorLastName);
        System.out.println("Title is: " + books.get(i).title);
        System.out.println("The publisher is: " + books.get(i).publisher);
        System.out.println("The category is: " + books.get(i).category);
        System.out.println("The date is: " + books.get(i).date);
     // do something with the HashMapped books, maybe use a scanner for a book lookup.
}
```

Bonus, I'm not sure if you'd want this considering you said you wanted to store all of the books within an ArrayList, however you can ditch all the extra code and the Book class entirely with this main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("bestsellers.txt");
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
      while (!(buf.readLine() == null) {
            lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
             wordsArray = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
              System.out.println("Author's first name is: " + wordsArray[0]);
        System.out.println("Author's last name is: " + wordsArray[1]);
        System.out.println("Title is: " + wordsArray[2]);
        System.out.println("The publisher is: " + wordsArray[3]);
        System.out.println("The category is: " + wordsArray[5]);
        System.out.println("The date is: " + wordsArray[4]);
            }
}
```

All it does is print off statements, but that should work.